# Архитектура простого Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, frontend

Делаю диплом. 
Вопрос трезво ли я рассуждаю? Что можете посоветовать?

Frontend должен выполнять функции отправлять на сервер картинки, отображать полученную из картинок трехмерную модель.

Пользователь может зарегистрироваться, посмотреть список восстановленных трехмерный моделей, и посмотреть трехмерную модель и еще 3-4 формы-диалога для пользователя есть.

Решил сделать *Single Page Application*. Чтобы было быстрее я не буду использовать фреймворки типа `Reactjs` их я не знаю, для 3D использую `Three.js`. Базовый класс для View будет Component. Component может включать в себя несколько кнопок и прочее.

Сигналы этих кнопок и прочего поднимаются до самого основного div Component'а, а после преобразуются в сигналы, которые обрабатываются классом Router.

Вообще любое взаимодействие между объектами происходит через Router. Вот примерная диаграмма классов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Свой велосипед! Классно! Самое сложное, на мой взгляд, в собственной реализации СПА - это url роутинг. Как вы собираетесь его решать? На мой взгляд - легче выучить angular, react или vue, чем делать свое. Предоставленная диаграмма классов без пояснений не очень понятна.